# R creating an array of matrices

Tags: r, data-structures

I would like to create an array of matrices in such a way that I first create an array of k matrices with NA values and then loop over k and update each k'th matrix through the array.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm probably missing the point, but won't:

```
k = 2; n=3; m = 4
array(NA, c(n,m,k))

, , 1

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA

, , 2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

give you what you want? Then you can loop as normal:

```
R> for(k in 1:2){print(a[,,k])}
```

Comment: Or for "simple" functions, don't even need the loop, thanks to R's vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

Beware of terminology :-) . As CSGillespie points out, you can define an N-rank array in `R` .  Alternatively, you could create a `list` variable, each entry of which contains a matrix.  The advantage to the latter is that the matrices can be of differing sizes. The disadvantage is that it can be rather more painful to create the inital state.

E.g.

```
mat1 <- matrix(NA, 3,5)
mat2 <- matrix(NA, 4,7)
matlist <- list(mat1=mat1,mat2=mat2)
```